# How to show the total match count in swiper?

Tags: ivy, swiper

When using swiper for search, it only shows the number of matching lines. How can I view the number of matches?

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported, so you may want to submit a feature request: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues

Comment: Support for this was added in a new command `swiper-isearch`. See https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1931

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1931#issuecomment-479513287

"Please test swiper-isearch. It's no longer line-based like swiper, which makes it display the total number of matches. It also fixes the slow startup of swiper"

Answer (score -2):

```
(setq ivy-display-style 'fancy
        ivy-count-format "(%d/%d) " ; this is what you want
        ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil ; remove initial ^ input.
        ivy-extra-directories nil ; remove . and .. directory.)
```

This is from the `:init` of my `(use-package swiper ...)` declaration.

Comment: `ivy-count-format` shows the current out of the total number of matching **lines**, not **substrings**. This does not do what OP is asking for.